# Comprobar las variables de entorno

Tags: go

Buen dia
Estoy adentrándome en Go para aprender y explorando código de otros hay líneas que no entiendo bien como funcionan

```
func EnvVar() string {
    log.Println("Reading environment info!")
    //Reading of ENVIRONMENT
    PortApi := GetEnvDefault("ENV_BAP_GO_PORT", ":8080")
    log.Println("Variables de entorno obtenidas...")
    return PortApi
}
// GetEnvDefault request from ENV_VAR pre-define
func GetEnvDefault(key, defVal string) string {
    val, ex := os.LookupEnv(key)
    if !ex {
        return defVal
    }
    return val
}
```

1. En la linea 1 usa usa la funcion con EnvVar() , entiendo que esta comprueba las variables de entorno , las cuales son GOROOT, GOPATH, GORUTH. pero no entiendo por que las checa, si estuvieran mal causaría un problema o error.
2. En la linea 4 PortApi := GetEnvDefault simplemente no entiendo que es el "key" investigando parece ser u valor que compone el ambiente (que es el ambiente? tengo una carpeta con ese nombre) pero que variable carga con sigo?

de antemano gracias

Answer (score 1):

Buenas Claus como estas ?

En la documentación del package os encontramos la firma para el método

```
func LookupEnv(key string) (string, bool)
```

Y una explicación de su funcionamiento :

> LookupEnv recupera el valor de la variable de entorno nombrada por la
> clave. Si la variable está presente en el entorno, se devuelve el
> valor (que puede estar vacío) y el valor booleano es verdadero. De lo
> contrario, el valor devuelto estará vacío y el valor booleano será
> falso.

En este caso, estas llamando a tu método GetEnvDefault con los parámetros "ENV_BAP_GO_PORT" y ":8080".

```
PortApi := GetEnvDefault("ENV_BAP_GO_PORT", ":8080")
```

Tu función GetEnvDefault hace lo siguiente :

```
func GetEnvDefault(key, defVal string) string {
    val, ex := os.LookupEnv(key)
    if !ex {
        return defVal
    }
    return val
}
```

Recibe un string que es la key, en este caso "ENV_BAP_GO_PORT" y un defaultValue que es lo que devuelve en caso de no encontrar esta variable de entorno.

Por tanto, si encuentra esta variable te va a devolver el value y sino te va a devolver :8080 como un string.

En este caso no estas buscando ninguna de las variables GOROOT, GOPATH, GORUTH como tu querías, esto puedes hacerlo simplemente llamando a LookupEnv pasándole estos valores como string.

Si tu necesidad es cargar muchas variables puedes crear un slice o array de variables y pasarle esto a un método tuyo que imprima estas variables de la siguiente manera :

```
func EnvVar() {
    log.Println("Reading environment info!")
    envVariablesToPrint := []string{"GOROOT", "GOPATH", "GORUTH"}
    //Reading of ENVIRONMENT
    for _, env := range envVariablesToPrint {
        val, ex := os.LookupEnv(env)
        if !ex {
            log.Println(fmt.Sprintf("Variable %s no encontrada", env))
        } else {
            log.Println(fmt.Sprintf("Variable %s encontrada con el valor: %s", env, val))
        }
    }
}
```